# Multi-thread support in IPad, IPhone

Tags: multithreading, ipad

Just to confirm if multithreading is supported in iPad and iPhone. I need to write an application that calls a web service on a background thread while user can still interact with the UI.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Regarding this question, read the manual. Apple has concise documentation that covers this. Also, it would do you good to select some answers and set a real username for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS has always supported multi-threading, just as Mac OS X did before it.  Here's Apple's excellent overview documentation on the subject: 
[Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has threads.

Also, you don't need to spawn your own threads for most tasks.  A lot of the Apple Frameworks (Cocoa Touch Foundation frameworks) have built-in code that will do this for you.

Also, if you're consuming data from a Web API (HTTP Request), I highly recommend you take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which is built on top of NSOperation (an operation class that easily handles background processing).

Finally, if you need help on program design/flow using the Model-View-Controller pattern, I've written a blog entry describing [how to consume Web API](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/10/15/how-to-consume-json-or-xml-web-apis-on-iphone-smoothly/) data and present it to the end-user in a table format.